# Accent in commented code in a C program

Tags: c, comments

I'm writing a little introduction in a file `my_program.c` on a MAC OS Sierra 10.21. The point is that I have to give this file to a professor who has Scientific Linux on his PC and, of course if i put a `printf` with an accent inside, *i. e.*

```
% code %
printf("This is an accent àèíóù \n");
% more code %
```

the program gives some strange issues. But I would like to know what happens if i put the accent inside a comment, *i.e.*

```
% code %
/* this is an accent inside a comment àèíóù */
% more code %
```

Will it have some problems compiling or executing the program?

Comment: What are the "strange issues"? And did you try putting accented characters in a comment? It seems like a very simple experiment.

Comment: I tried, but on my Mac OS X, and I don't know if there are same rules between different operative system, for examples on my Mac I can put in a printf whatever I want, while on Scientific Linux, if i try to print an accent i get strange characters...

Comment: that has to do with your terminal settings and locale, and not with the C programming language. There are a number of related questions already answered on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything inside your comments, no problem. Except for the closing tag( */ ), in case of multiline comments.

EDIT:

Check [some rules](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-comment-rules/) for c comments